# How to display all information from database in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to display all the information from database into my aspx web application. I have problem in understanding looping. :(

These are the vb code for  background code:-
I have problem for this part. which it doesnt display all information. Instead, it only shows 1 row of it. which is "dan" only

```
        Dim tryList() As String = {"saya", "dan"}

        For Each x As String In tryList
           listJE.Add(x)
        Next

        For Each str As String In listJE
            Lbl.Text = str
        Next
```

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Let me ask you this: if you have three cans of paint and you paint your wall from the first one, then the second one, then the third one, what will you see?  You'll just see the last colour you painted, right?  Now ask yourself what you can reasonably expect to happen if you set the `Text` of a `Label` to one value from a list, then another value from the list.  Why would you expect to be able to see the first value?

Comment: @jmcilhinney so in this case, my problem is in the listJE part isnt?

Comment: If you do this: lbl.text+=str probably you will see all values, if everything else is correct!

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan, that's what I did to mine and I successfully shows all the info. :D